# "Print selected rows" option missing in Event Participant listing dropdown actions

Tags: civievent, advanced-search

After a recent upgrade from 4.7.29 to 5.2.1 (Joomla) I am experiencing the following problem:

After doing an Events/Find Participants search and selecting some or all participants, the "Print selected rows" option in no longer appearing in the Actions dropdown.

An Advanced Search when displaying results as Event Participants also is missing this option.  The option does appear when results are displayed as Contacts.

I have verified the same behavior on dmaster.demo (running 5.4.alpha1).

Answer (score 4):

This is a core bug introduced during refactoring of task action. I have submitted core PR at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12310 . Can you please and if possible comment on PR your test results.

Issue logged at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/185

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Comment submitted - Thank you for identifying the problem!

Comment: Sorry, I had used different link for my fix. Updated it now!

Comment: Pradeep's patch has been merged for 5.3.0 (you can get a copy to test in https://download.civicrm.org/latest - it's in rc & will be released first Wed of July)

Comment: (note the regression occurred prior to 5.x so it is not recent enough to warrant a patch release - which is what we would do had it regressed in 5.1 or 5.2)

Answer (score 0):

Checking on some older systems I have, it was present in 4.7.27 and not in 4.7.31 so it seems to have disappeared somewhere between 4.7.29 and 4.7.31.  Please log an issue at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues